# Perform Left, Right and Inner join in Hazelcast Jet

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am working on Hazelcast jet application and I trying to join two Sources using Left, Right or Inner Join but I am stuck at below:

Here is my code:

```
BatchStage<Map<String,Object>> batch1= pipeline.readFrom(companyListBatchSource);
BatchStage<Map<String,Object>> batch2= pipeline.readFrom(employeeListBatchSource);

//Getting group by key
 BatchStageWithKey<Map<String,Object>, Object> jdbcGroupByKey = batch1.groupingKey(a -> a.getSource1().get(col1));
 BatchStageWithKey<Map<String,Object>, Object> fileGroupByKey = batch2.groupingKey(b -> b.getSource1().get(col2));

//trying to join but not sure what exactly is happening.
BatchStage<Entry<Object, Tuple2<List<Map<String,Object>>, List<Map<String,Object>>>>> d = jdbcGroupByKey.aggregate2(AggregateOperations.toList(),fileGroupByKey,AggregateOperations.toList());
```

From above code how can achieve data in **BatchStage<Map<String,Object>>** format? How we can apply different kind of joins here?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Map<String, Object>` represents a single item, let's call that entire type `E`. So your input is two streams of type `E`: companies and employees.

The result of a JOIN isn't of the type `E`, but, in full generality, `Tuple2<List<E>, List<E>>`.

From here on the details depend on the cardinalities of each side of the join. If you group by company on both sides, you should have a one-to-many association and the result type `Tuple2<E, List<E>>`. In this case, use `AggregateOperations.pickAny()` for the company stream, this will result in a single item and the result of the join will come out as `Entry<Object, Tuple2<List<E>, List<E>>>`. This is the equivalent of a LEFT OUTER JOIN. You get an inner join from that if you filter out all results where the list of employees is empty: `joined.filter(e -> !e.getValue().f1().isEmpty())`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is little new to me, so you are saying if I will use it :                      BatchStage<Entry<Object, Tuple2<List<Map<String,Object>>, List<Map<String,Object>>>>> d = jdbcGroupByKey.aggregate2(AggregateOperations.pickAny(),fileGroupByKey,AggregateOperations.toList());   then this will become left join?

Comment: Also how we can convert final output to BatchStage<Map<String,Object>> format, as after this I have to join it with other 4 Sources also.

Comment: if you use `pickAny()`, then you don't get `List<E>` in the output but just `E`. As for converting to `Map<String, Object>`, which is just `E` in your example, how you do that is up to your custom logic that combines the left and right objects.